# Append CSS style depending on image location directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, content-management-system, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to add or append a class to an image depending on the location of the image.

Background: I am re-writing my companies current to use Twitter Bootstrap. The current site uses a CMS (that uses CKEditor) for the monkeys to add text and upload images. I would like to apply the bootstrap class "img-responsive" everything they upload.  But I do not want to apply this class to image I use for the site core (i.e. logos, look and feel, etc…). Their images are uploaded to the /images/ directory and the site images are located in /siteimages/.

Before:

```
<img src="/images/gorilla.png" />
<img src="/images/monkey.jpg" />
<img src="/siteimages/logo.jpg" />
<img class=”drunk” src="/images/chimp.gif" />
```

After

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="/images/gorilla.png" />
<img class="img-responsive" src="/images/monkey.jpg" />
<img src="/siteimages/logo.jpg" />
<img class="drunk img-responsive" src="/images/chimp.gif" />
```

Is this possible?  Or I am over thinking this?  Any help or leads would be greatly appreciated.

A cheesy work around option I am thinking about is to apply the “img-responsive” declarations to all “img” and create a new “no-img-responsive” for the site images.  But I would like a slicker implementation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go in pure javascript :

```
<img src="/images/gorilla.png" />
<img src="/images/monkey.jpg" />
<img src="/siteimages/logo.jpg" />
<img class="drunk" src="/images/chimp.gif" />

<script>
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) {
    var img=imgs[i];
    if (img.src.indexOf('siteimages')==-1) {
        var classes=img.className;
        classes = (classes!='') ? classes+' img-responsive' : 'img-responsive';
        img.className=classes;
    }
}
</script>
```

the img classes has now been altered

```
<img src="/images/gorilla.png" class="img-responsive">
<img src="/images/monkey.jpg" class="img-responsive">
<img src="/siteimages/logo.jpg">
<img class="drunk img-responsive" src="/images/chimp.gif">
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to use the Jquery filter function to return the current "src" on targeted img or by modifying this function with a conditionnal (if ...).

```
$('img[src^="*yourPath*"]')
        .not('*the other path*']')
        .addClass ('*img-responsive*');
```

It will check the "src" condition on your uploaded images.

Comment: be careful with jQuery filter function: `$('img[src^="*yourPath*"]')` where `^` means `starts with`, `*` means `contains` and `$` means `ends with`

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the precision.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery to check image src attribute on document ready and apply img-responsive to all the images that their src starts with "/images"

Other solution is to use [Less](http://lesscss.org/)